# Django South - turning a null=True field into a null=False field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

My question is, what is the best practice for turning a `null=True` field into a `null=False` field using Django South. Specifically, I'm working with a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Do you know what the new default value will be for the foreign key column after null=False? Rather, will it be same for all or will some special processing need to take place to determine what it will be? Will there be a default? What database are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write first a data migration: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html
and then make the schemamigration.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn nullable ForeignKey into non-nullable one, then it can be problematic if you have any rows with NULL for that field (column). In such case you need to either remove or fix them - possibly with custom data migration, like `diegueus9` mentioned in the other answer.

But if you don't have any rows with NULL in that column, e.g. because you put that null=True only in case you might need it in the future, then you should be able to do a simple automatic schema migration:

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration myapp remove_null_from_fkey --auto
(...)
$ ./manage.py migrate myapp
```