# In a schemamigration, what should be the default value for a null=False field which I'm sure that won't have null values?

Tags: django, django-south

I want to add a `ForeignKey` field to my model. In order to achieve that, I did 3 steps:

1. Added the `ForeignKey` field with `null=True` to my model, and then created a `schemamigration`.
2. Created a `datamigration` in order to fill that foreign key with a sensible value. After this migration is applied, I'm pretty sure there is no object left with a NULL value at that field.
3. Changed that `ForeignKey` field to `null=False`, and then created another `schemamigration`.

However, I'm having problems at the **step 3**:

```
? The field 'MyModel.fkfield' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
? Since you are making this field non-nullable, you MUST specify a default
? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
? Please select a choice:
```

Well... No default value makes sense for this field, and also by now I'm pretty sure no object has that field as NULL. So... **I don't know how to answer this question correctly.** If I could, I would say "don't set any default value, and throw an error if you find any NULL in that column".

For now, as a workaround just to get over that question, I'm choosing option `2` and then using `1` as the one-off default value. This is a quite bad solution, but at least `south` doesn't complain about it and creates the migration.

- What is the correct way of changing a field into `NOT NULL`? (using `south`)
- What should I do when `south` asks me for a default value for a field that shouldn't have one?

I'm using `django-1.2` and `south-0.7`.

---

Related question: [Django South - turning a null=True field into a null=False field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761048/django-south-turning-a-null-true-field-into-a-null-false-field)

Related documentation: [Part 3: Advanced Commands and Data Migrations](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html)

*(footnote: here at StackOverflow we have two tags that seem equal for me: "django-south" and "south", but I don't have enough reputation to suggest synonyms)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just a thought: Since this is a foreign key, you can set the default value to a record you know will never have a referenced record, i.e. 0 or -1.  Your db will raise an error if south will actually try to use this default.

Comment: I generally allow NULL on all fields. This may be considered bad practice by some, but I personally believe the constraint that something must have a value should be enforced in the app not on the database.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's fine in theory, but what happens when more than the one well behaving application is accessing the DB?